# Open ground on my tester

Tags: electrical

I have a living room circuit in which the upper end of receptacles are turned on by a switch. I recently replaced all of the receptacles to color coordinate. I have a open ground on one of the receptacles whearas all other receptacles check fine with my tester. Only (1) receptacle is grounded. All others
do not have a ground wire. Can it be the receptacle? I live in Ohio

Comment: Not quite following your question but I understand the top receptacle being switched. with metal boxes and conduit the conduit could be the ground and why things look ok with only 1 grounded. And only one showing open.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: yes, it can be the receptacle